# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar todos los resultados de una consulta en access y mostrarla en excel por medio de VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, vb, ms-access-2010

Verán tengo el siguiente problema; pasa que quiero mostrar desde una consulta (select * from) toda la info de esa tabla y mostrarla en una hoja de excel mediante vba (mi tabla esta compuesta por campo1,campo2, y solo contiene dos registros) sin embargo no logro saber como realizar este paso por más que busco, ya que tengo un ejemplo similar que lo hace pero solo con un registro, es decir; el resultado de mi consulta trae dos registros, pero solo puedo recorrer uno con la siguiente senetencia:

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim datos As Object

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

consultaSQL = "SELECT * FROM Tickets order by 1"
Set datos = cn.Execute(consultaSQL)

campo = datos.Fields(2)
```

intente recorrerlo con un for pero al hacer esto solo me trae el valor del campo 2  del primer registro,  (usando datos.Fields(2)) no logro acceder al siguiente registro o mas bien cuál sería la sentencia para recorrer fila y columna de la consulta. Realmente necesito algo como recorrer el objeto de manera como datos[1,1] o algo similar, sólo hallé una sentencia como recordset, aunque menciona que la info la trae de formularios o componentes de tipo lista y aún así, ocupando esa función me sale error, creo es por el tipo de conexión con ADO y ADODB.
Espero me puedan ayudar, muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿ has probado a usar DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "Tabla/Consulta", Archivo Excel, True/False ?, es una forma fácil de exportar a excel. Pero ¿ porque no muestras los datos en un informe o es que que después vas a hacer algo con los datos en el Excel ?

Comment: mira [Range.CopyFromRecordset (Excel)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.range.copyfromrecordset). Aplicado a tu ejemplo, algo tipo `Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset datos` debería funcionar